# Using Ros Apartment gem with ruby 3.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

After updating ruby version from 2.7.4 => 3.0.0 seems that ros-apartment gem cannot switch between tenants.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `decode' for URI:Module):
  
lib/rescued_tenant_elevator.rb:10:in `block in call'
lib/rescued_tenant_elevator.rb:10:in `call'
```

After searching in documentation of ros-apartment seems that the problem is on generic call after calling @app.call(env)

My class for switching tenants

```html
require 'apartment/elevators/subdomain'

class RescuedTenantElevator < ::Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain
  def call(env)
    super
  rescue Apartment::TenantNotFound
    [302, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/hml', 'Location' => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_url }, self]
  end

  # needed to work
  def each
  end
end
```

Any idea ??

Comment: [Please don't cross-post.](https://github.com/rails-on-services/apartment/issues/202)

Answer (score 0):

Until apartment gem release any change about that i fixed it re-adding the URI methods in init

```
module URI
  def URI.decode(url)
    url
  end

  def URI.escape(url)
    url
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Where do i have to put the module?